# Use FormatNumber with the lib PX.Export.Excel.Core.Package

Tags: acumatica

Is there a tutorial on this function PX.Export.Excel.Core.Package ?
I would like use the formatnumber in the row (2,5) ?

```
var excel = new PX.Export.Excel.Core.Package();
var sheet = excel.Workbook.Sheets[1];
string fileNumber = un_order.OrderNbr +"___"+GetUniqueFileNumber();
sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 15);
sheet.Add(2, 5, decimalnumber);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How we might create Excel file in Acumatica using standard dll library of Acumatica website.
How we might import data from excel file to Acumatica using XLSXReader from PX.Data.dll library.

Example will be developed on Stock Item screen.
Export data to Excel file:

[image]

We will use PX.Export.dll library, so first you need add it to References:

[image]

2. Create new Package() object from the PX.Export.Excel.Core namespace and take first sheet from package.

[image]

3. Use method Add() on sheet object

Here is full example of source code logic that attach the excel file to Stock Item screen.

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.SM;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

namespace ExportExcelLib
{
    public class InventoryItemMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;

        public PXAction<InventoryItem> ExportExcel;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Export Excel", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton]
        public virtual IEnumerable exportExcel(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            if (this.Base.Item.Current == null) return adapter.Get();

            ExportToExcel(this.Base.Item.Cache, this.Base.Item.Current);

            return adapter.Get();
        }

        public virtual void ExportToExcel(PXCache cache, InventoryItem inventoryItem)
        {
            var excel = new PX.Export.Excel.Core.Package();
            var sheet = excel.Workbook.Sheets[1];

            sheet.Add(1, 1, "Inventory ID");
            sheet.Add(1, 2, "Item Description");
            sheet.Add(1, 3, "Item Status");
            sheet.Add(1, 4, "UOM");
            sheet.Add(1, 5, "Default Price");

            sheet.Add(2, 1, inventoryItem.InventoryCD);
            sheet.Add(2, 2, inventoryItem.Descr);
            sheet.Add(2, 3, inventoryItem.ItemStatus);
            sheet.Add(2, 4, inventoryItem.BaseUnit);
            sheet.Add(2, 5, (double)inventoryItem.BasePrice);

            // this logic conver Excel file to Memory Stream and bin format, after you could attache or save file to disk
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            UploadFileMaintenance fileUpload = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();

            excel.Write(ms);

            var oneFileInfo = new PX.SM.FileInfo(Guid.NewGuid(), "NewExcelFile.xlsx", null, ms.ToArray());
            fileUpload.SaveFile(oneFileInfo, FileExistsAction.CreateVersion);
            PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile(cache, inventoryItem, oneFileInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Screen shot of the excel file:

[image]

PS.: According to response from Acumatica Support the PX.Export.dll library doesn’t allow export images to excel file, method AddPng() will be removed in future:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yuriy :) Decimal number=123.123; // sheet.Add(cpt, 5, number,"0.00",-1);

Comment: For Date, we can use : sheet.Add(cpt, 18, vardate,"dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: Thanks, these are important details. Will add them in my fugure blog article